# What to use instead of "goto"-method?

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to programming, and I've realized that people reaaalllyy don't like "goto"-methods. I was wondering how one might write code that allows a user to decide how many entries to put in? For example, in the code below, the user inputs a name, and is then asked wether he/she wants to input another name. How could I do this without having to use go-to method?

```
public class GoToTest
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        InputName:
        string name;
        Console.Write("Input name: ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();

        string decision;
        Console.WriteLine(""); //Empty line for increased readability
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to input another name? Yes - No");
        decision = Console.ReadLine();
        if (decision == "Yes")
        {
            goto InputName;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name is " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a loop such as `while`

Comment: Slap a `while (true) {..}` around your logic, and then in your `if` do `if (decision != "Yes" break;`.

Comment: You could make it easier on the user: allow just a "y" or "n" as a response, and make it case-insensitive.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Your comment reminds of a mainframe system I used once where you literally had to type `Continue` to get to the next page in a list :)

Answer (score 5):

A good pattern to do this is an "infinite" loop that you break off when a certain condition is met:

```
while (true) {
 var input = GetInputFromConsole();
 if (input == "exit")
  break;
}
```

The closing brace of the while loop is pretty much a goto to the top. Yet, this is better than goto because the loop provides scope for variables and visual indentation. It is easier to comprehend.

Comment: As I stated in comment to another answer, I do not consider it a "good pattern". But since this code is short and clear, it can probably be good and readable in such simple case, so I don't feel an urge to downvote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like while(true) in general, So I had to give this answer.

```
do
{
    string name = GetName();
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to input another name? (Y)es - (N)o");
}while(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().StartsWith("Y"));
```

and GetName may look like below.

```
string GetName()
{
    Console.Write("Input name: ");
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: But aren't you consuming more memory by doing the ToUpper(), and StartsWith() versus looping until the value equals another value such as the answer provided by @usr?

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't matter. Optimize only where it matters. I would like my player to press only "Y" or 'y'. That's general practice for getting user input.

Comment: I think breaking off the loop in this delayed way is just backwards. Break the loop at the point where you determine it should be stopped. Don't set a flag to have it stopped later.

Comment: @usr, I liked your answer, but while(true) is the devil sometimes, I like to avoid them as far as possible.

Comment: +1 for not liking *while(true)*. *while(true)* with *break* is essentially camouflaged way of writing *goto*.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek it is kind of true what you are saying. I'm still trying to pin-point why exactly I think the while-true loop is better. But even if it was just a goto in disguise - the same goes for this condition-based loop.

Comment: I don't agree. Condition based loop shows a clear intention of what loop execution depends on. Loop based on *while(true)* moves condition to one or more *break* statements and program loses on clarity. Anyway, my programming teacher in high school would fail me for using *break* (or *continue*; he discouraged those just as *goto* statement) :)

Comment: You could always do a recursive method to really avoid while(true), especially in this case.

Comment: @MikeCofoed don't do that. If the user wants to keep inputting values, eventually you will use up your entire stack.

Comment: Using recursion here is even more convoluted. It's building up a callstack of frames that have nothing to do with the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it tidier by checking for the exit condition like this:

```
string decision = "y";
while (decision == "y")
{
    string name;
    Console.Write("Input name: ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Name is " + name);
    Console.Write("\nWould you like to input another name? y/n: ");
    decision = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
}
```

(`\n` inside a string gives you a new line.)

Or you could make it even easier on the user by letting them hit enter on its own when they have finished entering names:

```
string name = "x"; // anything except an empty string
Console.WriteLine("Enter a blank line to finish...");
while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
{
    Console.Write("\nInput name: ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name is " + name);
    }
}
```

I used `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)` in case a user decides that a blank line means space(s) or tab(s).